# How can I remove the security/malicious user warning from my website?

Tags: dns, heroku, cname

I have a domain name tradespring.net, and www.tradespring.net that redirect to my Heroku app with a CNAME record. However when I first try to access these sites it gives me a malicious warning.

> This is probably not the site you are looking for! blah blah blah
>   then "proceed anyways" or "back to safety"

Its because my browser realizes that it is redirecting. How can I make sure anyone's browser (not just my browser) trusts this site and my Heroku app?

I don't think i need an SSL certificate because this site is not sending sensitive info (credit card info, etc.).

Comment: Have you purchased your own SSL certificate?

Comment: I don't get an error, I'm only redirected to an adult site when going to www.tradespring.net (without www just a 403).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get your own SSL

"This warning is presented by a web browser when accessing a website that has a security certificate installed (for data encryption) that was issued to a domain other than the one being accessed."

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-name-mismatch-error.htm

In Chrome it tells me

```
"Google Chrome can say for sure that you reached *.herokuapp.com, but cannot verify that that is the same site as www.tradespring.net which you intended to reach. If you proceed, Chrome will not check for any further name mismatches."
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think i need an SSL certificate because this site is not sending sensitive info (credit card info, etc.).

So then [why is your app 301 redirecting HTTP to the HTTPS site](http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tradespring.net)? Don't do that and you won't get the certificate warning.

Have you followed [these directions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)?

Comment: yeah those are the directions I followed. I set up a CNAME record from http://www.tradespring.net (http) to https://tradespring.herokuapp.com  (https).

Comment: Strange, according to this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maximizing-availability/#dns__ssl it says `Apps on the Cedar stack should have CNAME records pointing to app-name.herokuapp.com. When SSL is required provision an SSL Endpoint and point your CNAME records to endpoint-name.herokussl.com. Any other configuration will result in reduced availability.` That leads me to believe it should not be ssl if your using herokuapp.com

Comment: CNAMEs do not use protocol's either. somewhere on tradespring.net you must have a 301 redirect. Maybe it's inside .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file for a http to https redirect and remove it.

Since your website does not handle sensitive information, you need not waste money on an SSL certificate.

https:// is used only when there is a valid SSL certificate installed on the server. An error will be thrown if the certificate is missing.